# Returning useful error messages with PHP

Tags: php

I don't understand how to properly create and return useful error messages with PHP to the web.

I have a class

```
class Foo {
    const OK_IT_WORKED = 0;
    const ERR_IT_FAILED = 1;
    const ERR_IT_TIMED_OUT = 3;

    public function fooItUp(){
        if(itFooed)
          return OK_IT_WORKED;
        elseif(itFooedUp)
          return ERR_IT_FAILED;
        elseif(itFooedOut)
          return ERR_IT_TIMED_OUT;
    }
}
```

And another class that uses this class to do something useful, then return the result to the user. I am just wondering where I put the string value for all my error messages.

```
class Bar {
    public function doFooeyThings(stuff){
        $res = $myFoo->fooItUp();
        // now i need to tell the user what happened, but they don't understand error codes
        if($res === Foo::OK_IT_WORKED)
           return 'string result here? seems wrong';
        elseif ($res === Foo::ERR_IT_FAILED)
           return Foo::ERR_IT_FAILED_STRING; // seems redundant?
        elseif($res === Foo:ERR_IT_TIMED_OUT)
           return $res; // return number and have an "enum" in the client (js) ?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid returning error states whenever possible. Use exceptions instead. If you've never used exceptions before you can read about them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

There multiple ways you can utilize exceptions in your example. You could create custom exceptions for every error or for every category of error. More on custom exceptions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) or you could create an instance of the default `Exception` class supplying it the error messages as strings.

The code below follows the second approach:

```
class Foo {
    const OK_IT_WORKED = 0;
    const ERR_IT_FAILED = 1;
    const ERR_IT_TIMED_OUT = 3;

    public function fooItUp(){
        if(itFooed)
          return OK_IT_WORKED;
        else if(itFooedUp)
           throw new Exception("It failed")
        else if(itFooedOut)
           throw new Exception("Request timed out");
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can think of some more elegant messages than the ones I used. Anyway, you can then go ahead and handle those exceptions on the caller method using try/catch blocks:

```
class Bar {
    public function doFooeyThings(stuff){
        try
        {
           $res = myFoo->fooItUp();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
           //do something with the error message
        }

    }

}
```

Whatever exception is thrown from `fooItUp` will be "caught" by the `catch` block and handled by your code.

Two things you should also consider are:

- It's best not to show your users detailed information about errors because those information could be used by users with malicious intent
- Ideally you should have some kind of global exception handling

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use exceptions in conjunction with `set_exception_handler()`.

```
<?php

set_exception_handler(function($e) {
    echo "Error encountered: {$e->getMessage()}";
});

class ErrorMessageTest
{
    public function isOk()
    {
        echo "This works okay. ";
    }

    public function isNotOkay()
    {
        echo "This will not work. ";
        throw new RuntimeException("Violets are red, roses are blue!! Wha!?!?");
    }
}

$test = new ErrorMessageTest();

$test->isOk();
$test->isNotOkay();
```

The `set_exception_handler()` method takes a callable that will accept an exception as its parameter.  This let's you provide your own logic for a thrown exception in the event it isn't caught in a `try/catch`.

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/RKCPe)

See also: [set_exception_handler() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)